# Prove that for any positive integer $a$, $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that for any positive integer $a$, $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}$.

---

What I have :
Using FLT
$$a^{561} = a^{3 \cdot187} \equiv a^{187} = a^{3\cdot62}a^1 \equiv a^{62}a^1 = a^{3\cdot21} \equiv a^{21}=a^{3\cdot7}\equiv a^7 = a^{2\cdot3}a^1 \equiv a^2a^1 = a^3 \equiv a \pmod 3.$$
Similar calculations for $\mod {11}$ and $\mod {17}$ show that $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{11, 17}$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod {561}$, as desired. $\square$

**Case 2:** $\gcd(a, 561) > 1$. This implies that $a$ is divisible by at least one of $3, 11,$ or $17$.

---

I Don't know what to do for case 2.

Comment: if $3\nmid a$, then $a^2\equiv1\pmod3$, so $a^{561}\equiv (a^{2})^{280}a\equiv a\pmod 3$

Comment: for case $2$, can you prove by induction that $a^{2n+1}\equiv a^{2n-1}a^2\equiv a^3\equiv a\pmod 3$ ?

Comment: [Carmichael numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) might interest you.

Comment: ^^Yes,  I know. @J.W.Tanner, I will try that.

Comment: I tried, but I can't get it right. Can someone help. Could Euler's Theorem be helpful??

Comment: Where do you use that gcd (561,a)=1 in case 1?

Comment: $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$ is valid for all $a$. Dividing both sides by $a$ (with the assumption that $(a,p)=1$), we have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ whether or not $(a,p)=1$.

Show by induction that $a^{(p-1)n+1}\equiv a\pmod p$,

using $a^{(p-1)n+1}=a^{(p-1)(n-1)+1}a^{p-1}=a^{(p-1)(n-1)}a^p\equiv a^{(p-1)(n-1)+1}\pmod p$.

Comment: I tried it his way and solved a second time, Thank You!.

Answer (score 0):

If $3 \mid a$, then $a^{561} \equiv a \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Otherwise, if $3 \not\mid a$, you also have $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{3}$ using what you did using Fermat's little theorem. You can similarly get $a^{561} \equiv a$ is always true for modulo $11$ and $17$. Since $561 = 3 \times 11 \times 17$, you thus have $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}$ is true for all $a$.

Comment: Thank You, I think I forgot that in Fermat's Last theorem, $a$ need not to be coprime to $p$.

Comment: @WWesEEE You're welcome. Note it's Fermat's little theorem you're referring to, with Fermat's last theorem being very different.

Comment: Oops i meant that, sorry.